# device-aspect-ratio is deprecated

Tags: css, iphone, web, device, iphone-5

for only identifying iPhone 5 device, I'm specifying css query with device-aspect-ratio.

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
// Styles will be applied only to iphone 5
}
```

But now i can see usage of device-aspect-ratio is not recommended anymore.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-aspect-ratio#browser_compatibility

to avoid using device-aspect-ratio, i tried some other approaches

```
@media (device-height : 568px) 
and (device-width : 320px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation : landscape) {
// Styles will be applied to all devices [iphone 6/7/8....]
}
```

The problem is, the styles is getting applied to other phone devices[iphone 6/7/8/x/12/13..] which have large screen sizes.

Is there any better approach to put my styles only for iphone 5 device landscape mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **aspect-ratio**, with **min-|max-** prefixes, please, take a look on [this docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio).